# Spring Saml2 SP integration with angular App(I have implemented Saml2 Security in Backend now i want to connect to backend from Angular App)

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, saml-2.0, okta

We have developed an spring boot application with saml2 as the security mechanism our Spring boot app acts as SP and Okta and one more Saml provider as IDP. Now we want our Backend Spring boot app to be integrated with front end app which is in angular. Can anybody suggest the process that needs to be followed to achieve this to happen.
We have Used Saml2 service provider dependency, We have used relying party registration for configuring multiple Idps

Comment: I would use good ol' cookies to communicate between your frontend and backend. Do all the authentication on your backend, then serve up your frontend from the same port, and session cookies should work just fine. Doing SAML on the frontend is a lot more difficult on the frontend. Related: implementing SAML in 2021 is like implementing SOAP. OIDC is to SAML as REST is to SOAP.

Comment: Can you please provide any example of how this is implemented.  Like angular and spring boot  with saml on spring boot.

Comment: We have a tutorial on the Okta developer blog that shows SAML + Spring Boot. Unfortunately, it does not use Angular. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/10/14/spring-security-saml-database-authentication